# Combine two datasets based on month and location

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have two datasets consisting of monthly climatologies of chlorophyll concentration(chl a,yr 1970 - 2020) and fugacity of carbon dioxide(fco2y,yr 2002 - 2020). One of the datasets has the year values but the other dataset only has the month values. Is there any way I can merge the data based only on location and month attribute using python. I need to aggregate the data to fit regression model.?

Dataset 1

```
+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
|  lat   |    lon    |  chlor_a   | month |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
| 78.375 | 23.125006 |  2.1265152 |     1 |
| 78.375 |  23.20834 |  2.1265152 |     2 |
| 78.375 | 23.291674 |  2.1265152 |     2 |
| 78.375 |  24.95834 | 0.31348512 |     1 |
| 78.375 | 25.041674 | 0.31348512 |     3 |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Dataset 2

```
+----------+------+-------+--------------------+--+
|   DATE   |  LAT |  LON  |  FCO2_AVE_WEIGHTED |  |
+----------+------+-------+--------------------+--+
| 15-02-70 |  9.5 | 156.5 |            303.672 |  |
| 15-02-70 |  9.5 | 157.5 |            311.013 |  |
| 15-02-70 |  9.5 | 158.5 |            321.322 |  |
| 15-02-70 | 10.5 | 155.5 |            305.066 |  |
+----------+------+-------+--------------------+--+
```

Comment: in which form do you have the data? Dataframe of pandas or csv-File? What is the Location column?

Comment: The data is csv and the location column refers to the latitude and longitude.

Comment: @SirBaum I guess the location is the longitudes and latitudes

Comment: @Shreyas do you want to check if `LON` and `LAT` between the to dataframes have similar values, together with checking the months from `month` and `DATE` columns?

Comment: yes. i want to fit  a regression model on the aggregated data with fco2 as the target variable and chl, month and location as the independent variables . But as the year is missing in one data i am not sure how  i am supposed to map one data to another only on the basis of month and location.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date column into string data type if it is in datetime format and split it by '-' , in this way you will get month from table 2
After that merge both dataframe using df1.merge(df2,left_on=[df1 columns name],right_on=[df2 columns name])

Answer (score 0):

As Mohd already mentioned, you can achieve this basically with two pandas standard functions. I just quickly coded a ready-to-use solution for your problem. Please take a look and read the pandas documentation for further information.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[78.375,23.125006,2.1265152,1],[78.375,23.20834,2.1265152,2],[78.375,23.291674,2.1265152,2],[78.375,24.95834,0.31348512,1],[78.375,25.041674,0.31348512,3]],columns=['lat','lon','chlor_a','month'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['15-02-70',9.5,156.5,303.672],['15-02-70',9.5,157.5,311.013],['15-02-70',9.5,158.5,321.322],['15-02-70',10.5,155.5,305.066]],columns=['DATE','LAT','LON','FCO2_AVE_WEIGHTED'])

df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])
df2['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['DATE']).month
df2 = df2.rename(str.lower, axis='columns')
df2 = df2.merge(df1,on=['lat','lon','month'],how='outer')
print(df2)
```

I hope it helps you. Pandas is really a powerful library, which can easily achieve the desired functionality.